# How to generate dynamic tags for every instance launched using EC2 Launch Templates in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to tag my ec2 instances with a unique name every time I launch one using Launch Template. However I cannot find a way to do so.

I see solutions where we can tag resources using Lambdas but that solution doesn't really work for instances launched by Launch Templates as far as I can understand.

Is there a way to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Why lambda wouldn't work? This is how you can do it.

Comment: @Marcin I can't think of how the Launch Template can trigger the Lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generally two solutions for auto-tagging instances.

1. Enable CloudTrial trial and detect `run-instances` API call. This would be automatically picked up by a CloudWatch Rule which would trigger a lambda function. Details are in [Automatically tag new AWS resources based on identity or role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/auto-tag-aws-resources/).
2. Setup `UserData` in your Launch Template, so that the instance tags itself. This will require proper instance role with permissions for that. So its up to your use-case if you want to have such permissions for all instances.

Comment: I was also thinking along the lines of the second answer. Don't really want to complicate my architecture for a silly tag. Thanks for your answer.